# Microsoft BI - export all data from chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm new on Microsoft BI, my Boss asked me to find a way to export ALL THE DATA from a chart available in Dashboard rather than the cumulated values. It should work via a double-click on the pivot table, after the click you should be able see all the data related to the value.

Thanks everyone

Nick

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the built-in [data export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data?tabs=powerbi-desktop) functionality, you can [drill-through to another report page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drillthrough) that displays the details.